# How to remove multiple trailing slashes?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slash

Here are my rewrite rules:

```
###########
# Rewrite #
###########
# Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Cache Busting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^(.+)\.\d+\.(css|js)$" [NC]
RewriteRule "^.*$" "/%1.%2" [L]
# No Index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "\ /.*index\.php.*\ " [NC]
RewriteRule "^(.*)index\..+$" "/$1" [L,NC,R=301]
# No Question Mark
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "\ /[^?]*\?\ "
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/$1?" [L,R=301]
# WWW
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !"^(?:static|www)\.(.+)$" [NC]
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s "^on(s)|"
# RewriteRule "^(.*)$" http%2://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Everything works fine (any suggestion to improve performances or for better regexps is welcome, anyway) but I'm experiencing a weird situation and I can't understand if it's produced by my rewrite rules or by a default Apache behavior.
If my URL ends with a "/", I can append as many slashes as I want without it being rewritten.

For example, if in my address bar I insert the following:

> http://[MY-HOST-NAME]////////////////////////////

All those slashes are not being removed. And I'm still seeing my index.php page.
If I insert the following address:

> http://[MY-HOST-NAME]/members///

All those multiple slashes are not being removed and I can see my members index.php page.
And so on...

Can someone help me please? Many thanks!

Comment: Well, exactly which rule should rewrite the slashes, and why? (I wouldn't bother and treat too many slashes as "user error", but...)

Comment: Why should it matter? If *your website* doesn't ever add extra trailing slashes that shouldn't be there, then don't worry about it. Why waste extra HTTP requests to remove extra slashes that a user manually adds in, that will ultimately have no affect on what page gets displayed?

Comment: Why should it matter if it matters or not for me?
If you got a solution it's fine, post it. If you don't have just don't answer. I'm asking for it because I saw a good amount of bots requesting both "/" and "//" (including Google Bot), and this can make my index page being indexed two times in seach engines. Not really SEO friendly.

Comment: No need to get personal. With the info you provided I too would have answered the same. All websites have the same problem, even google (http://www.google.nl////). You should have just added the info in your comment to your original post. But to answer you question, the reason search engines spider the urls with superfluous slashes is most likely because the urls in your html have double slashes. Search engines don't normally guess urls. Also search engines are smart enough to know that those urls most likely mean the same. Just like they know that `/` is probably the same as `/index.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* $0 [R]
```

Comment: Damned! The world can be so easy. :-)

Comment: Not working for me in Apache either - I was redirected to the path of htdocs on the server

Comment: In that case I think you need to specify a `RewriteBase`. Something like `RewriteBase /` if the htaccess is located in the root.

Answer (score 1):

```
# rule 1: remove multiple leading slashes (directly after the TLD)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/{2,}
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=301,L]

# rule 2: remove multiple slashes in the requested path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Gerbens answer works well for .htaccess but not so much for global config. 
This one removes all the slashes before sending the redirect.

```
# if match set environment variable and start over
RewriteRule ^(.*?)//+(.*)$ $1/$2 [E=REDIR:1,N]

# if done at least one. redirect with 301
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIR} 1
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#existing rule
#remove the www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://local.website.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

#new Rule
#if its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#and it has a trailing slash then redirect to URL without slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# rest of your existing rules go here
```