# multiple slashes on url: how to remove?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Based on code found here: [remove multiple trailing slashes mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846225/remove-multiple-trailing-slashes-mod-rewrite)

I have the following htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteBase /

#
# remove multiple slashes from url
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]

#
# Remove multiple slashes anywhere in URL
#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Yet i found out the G-Bot has crawled this url: `http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/////////bbb-ccc/bbb-ddd.htm`. (aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, are keywords in url, not to be taken litraly - i jut show the pattern of the url)

Testing the above url in by live server i found out that the slash removal does not work.

Anyone can offer any tips or improvement to the the existing code? Thank you

**EDIT 1**
@Sylwester provided the following code

```
# if match set environment variable and start over
RewriteRule ^(.*?)//+(.*)$ $1/$2 [E=REDIR:1,N]

# if done at least one. redirect with 301
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIR} 1
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

It is not working either. I still see the ////// inside the url.
I have put this set of rules at the very top of my htaccess file, right below the " RewriteBase /", so as not to be affected by other rules, yet... nothing.
Any other suggestion?

Comment: So why do the answers in that other question not work for you?

Comment: @Juhana i have no idea

Comment: I managed to find the answer in a link you provided. I bet you can also.

Comment: @Sylwester so you read the article, tested it and post your answer.. you are fast... care to enlighten me also?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have tested it and it works for me in an .htaccess. My original answer was only tested in global config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per directory and .htaccess is tricky since apache actually have removed redundant slashed for us. Eg. there is no match for //+ anymore so we check the %{REQUEST_URI} since it has the original URI while the rewrite rule need to match anything:

```
# NB: Only works for per directory and .htaccess
# Needs "AllowOverride All" in global config for .htaccess 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"

Options +FollowSymlinks
# Check if the REQUEST_URI has redundant slashes
# and redirect to self if it has (which apache has cleaned up already)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} //+
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L]
```

If you can add global config I would have prefered this in the virtual host instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if match set environment variable and start over
RewriteRule ^(.*?)//+(.*)$ $1/$2 [E=REDIR:1,N]

# if done at least one. redirect with 301
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIR} 1
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i have tested your code and noting. See my edit1 section in original post.