# Delete last slash after hostname

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Using mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

I can delete last slash in links like example.com/foo/
But wat if i want to delete this last slash in example.com/ the rules used before dont work.
The same in this example:
If i want to delete 2 slashes

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

it works fine if link is somthing like example.com/foo//bar
But if the link is example.com//foo/bar the rule does not work.

Comment: the slash after the hostname is important as it represents your document root/public directory . It can not be omitted.

Comment: Thanks starkeen. But then wat to do in situations like this: example.com//foo/bar. How to make from those 2 // only one /.

Comment: If you want to remove multiple slashes from your url, eg : **example.com//foo/bar** you can use :

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/+(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]`

Answer (score 0):

you could:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(//)?(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

You can add /? to the condition. I can't test right now but maybe works.

Comment: Mork, please read well the question. There is no duplicate. Your answer still work like my rules.

Comment: I am asking about the traling slash just after the hostname (example.com/). All other traling slashes are deleted by my and Mork rules well.

Comment: changed answer, maybe add (//)?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]. Still does not work (((

Comment: The thing is that the string that RewriteRule works with never begins with a slash, as i understand. So the question is, wat to do in the case when the traling slash is just after host name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846225/remove-multiple-trailing-slashes-mod-rewrite

Comment: Do you find a solution?